# How to show that a relation is an equivalence relation given a defined relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I understand for the most part the conceptual aspects of an equivalence relation. A relation is considered a equivalence relation if it satisfies reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties but Im having trouble working with this on paper.

For example, 
Given a relation R defined on the integers by aRb <=> a+b is even, show that this relation is an equivalence relation.

So far my approach is. 
Reflexive, aRa <=> a+a is even 
Symmetric, if bRa <=> b+a is even
Transitive, if aRb and bRc then aRc <=>a+c is even.

But after that i am stuck.

Comment: You have the right definitions, now you need to apply them. For example, for reflexivity, as you wrote aRa <=> a+a is even. If a is an integer, can you see why a+a will always be even? The other properties are done similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the definition :

- reflexivity :
  $a+a = 2 a$ is even, so $aRa$
- symetric :
  if $aRb$ then a+b is even, then b+a is even then $bRa$
- transitive : if $aRb$ and $bRc$ then a+b is even and b+c is even, then a+2b+c is even then a+c is even (because 2b is even), then  $aRc$